# My Nas made a JBOD on 2 drives

Tags: raid, nas, ext, jbod

Thank you for reading this message and helping me.

***Context:*** 
I recently had a NAS (DNS320L) that was faulty and I sent it back.

It was a 2 bay NAS and I has a WD Green 1TB drive and a WD Red 4TB drive. I therefore set up a 1TB Raid 1 and a 3TB JBOD on the remaining space on WD Red.

I returned the DNS320L however I want to recover my files. Since nothing actually went wrong with the hard drives or RAID I bought a Hard drive dock to usb and connected the WD Red drive and copied all the files on the RAID 1 to my computer. However, that is all that shows up, the JBOD files do not show up.

***Problem***
I installed "DiskInternals Linux Reader" and was able to see what was going on:(as seen in images)
[image: WD Green 1TB Image]

[image: WD Red 4TB Image]

It seems as if the 1TB Green drive thinks it has the JBOD on it, and when I open a folder view of "HDb2" I see the folders of what I put in the JBOD. However, I am guessing that the actual data is on the 4TB red drive.

So now I am wondering if I need to have both drives connected simultaneously (by buying another hard drive dock to usb) in order to copy the JBOD files to my computer, or will this not work ?

Answer (score 0):

If you combined the RAID volume with a JBOD... you're screwed.  RAID 1 is redundant sure... but when you add a JBOD on top of it... you basically make your redundancy un-redundant.  Whatever was stored on the RAID 1 volume is probably in-tact... but all sectors on the remaining 3tb are gone.  (Notice, I said Sectors... not files).  From a logical-standpoint... imagine a 4tb disk... and 3tb just go-away.  What would you expect to happen?  Just because the 1st TB is redundant... it does nothing for the remaining 3tb of that logical-disk.  It is very unlikely you will recover much.  You could try some file-carving utilities... but it is doubtful that you'll have much luck.

Never mix RAID modes (and/or JBOD) in the same volume... unless you really REALLY know what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
There is just one thing I don't understand: "Imagine [...] 3tb just go away", why would the 3tb go away, the Raid did not fail or anything I simply took the drives out of a faulty NAS that I sent back. 
So connecting the 2 drives at the same time to the PC would not let the PC read the JBOD?

Comment: Just to clarify sorry, I knew the JBOD wouldn't be redundant, and the files there aren't crucial, it's just I have a large music collection on there and it would be annoying to have to rebuild it again. 
But the raid did not crash or fail, the NAS was faulty and stopped recognizing the drives because of the NAS' fault.

Comment: the 1tb drive and 1tb of the 4tb drive is part of a RAID 1 mirror.  Correct? ... the remaining 3tb on the 4tb drive is JBOD'd with the RAID'd volume.  Logically, they will appear as 1 disk... but underlaying, there will be 2 logical layers.  One is built on top of the other.  You may not have intended this, but it would explain why your 1tb disk shows up as a JBOD.

Comment: I think I must have said something wrong, It comes up as JBOD on the linux reader so I called it JBOD. 
When I formatted the drives in the NAS I set up: 1tb drive and 1tb of the 4tb drive as a RAid 1 correct. The rest of the space (so 3tb) on the WD RED 4tb drive was just a partition of 3tb. So on the NAS (and on my pc) there were 2 disks: the first disk mapped to Y was the RAID 1, and a second disk mapped to Z which was 3tb.
I am very grateful for you helping me out so I hope I haven't been wrongly calling it JBOD.

Comment: is hda the 1tb or is hdb the 1tb?

Comment: hda is the 1tb Raid

Comment: am I seeing things? .. it says hda2 is a RAID volume... mirror.... and hdb2 is the JBOD...

Comment: Yep it says that. 
Further information that can maybe help you? I can only get a folder view of hdb on the 1tb green drive and not on the 4tb REd drive, but it is definitely the hdb that has the folders for the 3tb partition I made on the 4tb red drive

Comment: I confess... at this point.. I honestly don't know what dlink is doing with the disk volumes... it is very strange.  A `fdisk -l` might shed some additional light... and maybe a `lvscan --all`.

Comment: I don't access to linux at the moment sorry. 
Do you think if I am able to mount the hdb present on the 1tb green drive and then connect the Red 4tb drive that I will be able to access the 3tb partition or is that fantasy?

Comment: Anything is possible... doubly-so if the RAID/JBOD can be assembled.

Comment: By any chance do you have any recommended ways of assembling the two drives?

Comment: Not in Windows.  Linux uses `mdadm`... assuming the disks are ok... you can simple reassemble the RAID.